# Can anyone translate this Chinese text? (Characters identified: 招財納福)

Tags: meaning, character-identification

My friend has a statue and there is some Chinese text on it. Can anyone translate it to English for me. Also, I would like to know more about this statue, any links, history about it, anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: praying for fortune and happiness.

Comment: It is 招财纳福(SC)/招財納福(TC), literally translate them word by word: attracting wealth, bringing felicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attracting money and happiness. It's very common to find these words under this specific buddha as it's its specialty.